# Convert array of objects into a single object seperated by "&"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, react-redux

I want to convert this array into a single object seperated by "&" like:

Input:

```
[
   {
      "data1":"Yes"
   },
   {
      "data2":"2"
   },
   {
      "data3":true
   }
]
```

required output:

```
{data1 :"Yes" & data2:"2" & data3:true}
```

Comment: Your input and output structure is not valid

Comment: you have to provide a valid expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reduce to iterate and using spread(...) to combine two object

```js
const arr = [{ data1: 'Yes' }, { data2: 2 }, { data3: true }];
const output = arr.reduce((obj, arrObject) => { 
    obj= {...obj, ...arrObject}
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Array.reduce`

**If your output is an object**: You have to define the accumulator as object

```js
const arr = [{ data1: 'Yes' }, { data2: 2 }, { data3: true }];
const output = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let key in curr) {
    acc[key] = curr[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output)
```

If your output needs to be `{data1 ="Yes" & data2="2" & data3=true}`, then this should be a string, because this syntax is not a valid javascript object.

**For that**

- keep accumulator as array
- push the values to array
- join the array using `&`
- print the output in string manipulated format.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arr = [{ data1: 'Yes' }, { data2: 2 }, { data3: true }];
const output = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let key in curr) {
    acc.push(`${key}=${curr[key]}`)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
const manipulatedOutput = `{${output.join(' & ')}}`;
console.log(manipulatedOutput);
```

Comment: I used it and got the same output but i want the objects seperated by & not comma like {data1 :"Yes" & data2:"2" & data3:true}

Comment: Then the output must be string, not array.

Comment: @Subodhshakya the output you want (`{data1 :"Yes" & data2:"2" & data3:true}`) would not be valid javascript code. The closest approximation you can get to that is either the *object* produced by @Nitheesh code or a *string* like `'{data1: "Yes" & data2: "2" & data3: true}'` (and in this case you might want to clarify which values should be enclosed between double-quotes and which ones shouldn't; for example, why `2` becomes `"2"` and `true` remains `true` instead of becomning `"true"`?)

Comment: @secan so the closest approximation i can get is a string '{data1: "Yes" & data2: "2" & data3: true}' ?

Comment: @Subodhshakya can you check my scond fiddle?

Comment: @Subodhshakya, well, whether that is the "closest approximation" depends on the meaning we give to "closest approximation" (as you said you expected an *object* as output, I'd consider "the closest approximation" `{data1: "Yes", data2: "2", data3: true}`), but yes, you can obtain the string `'{data1: "Yes" & data2: "2" & data3: true}'`

Comment: @Subodhshakya please approve the answer then.